# Passing a C# string through Pinvoke

Tags: c#, c++, .net, c, pinvoke

C# side:

```
    [DllImport(@"FileGuidUtils.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    private static extern long getReparseType([MarshalAsAttribute(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string linkPath);
```

C/C++ side:

```
__declspec(dllexport) ReparseType getReparseType(WCHAR *linkPath) {
    HANDLE hFile = CreateFile(linkPath, GENERIC_ALL, FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS | FILE_FLAG_OPEN_REPARSE_POINT, NULL);
    if (hFile == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        CloseHandle(hFile);
        return NEITHER;
    }

    REPARSE_DATA_BUFFER *reparseDataBuffer = (REPARSE_DATA_BUFFER *)malloc(MAXIMUM_REPARSE_DATA_BUFFER_SIZE);
    DWORD dwRetLen = 0;
    BOOL bRet = DeviceIoControl(hFile, FSCTL_GET_REPARSE_POINT, NULL, 0, reparseDataBuffer, MAXIMUM_REPARSE_DATA_BUFFER_SIZE, &dwRetLen, NULL);
    if (bRet == FALSE)
    {
        free(reparseDataBuffer);
        CloseHandle(hFile);
        return NEITHER;
    }

    ULONG reparseType = reparseDataBuffer->ReparseTag;
    free(reparseDataBuffer);
    CloseHandle(hFile);

    if (reparseType == IO_REPARSE_TAG_SYMLINK) {
        return SYMLINK;
    }
    else if (reparseType == IO_REPARSE_TAG_MOUNT_POINT) {
        return JUNCTION;
    }

    return NEITHER;
}
```

How is linkPath passed? Is it passed as a malloc'd string and I need to free it up on the C/C++ side or will the CLR take care of it for me? If it is getting cleaned up, am I passing it correctly? Could I just pass it as an ordinary C# string without the `[MarshalAsAttribute(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]`? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C# will make a copy of the C# string for you into unmanaged memory , pass a pointer to it and delete the string once the function call is finished

Comment: OK so as I understand what you've said, there's nothing I need to change?